# How to define a gaussian mixture model without needing to fit to data?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to define a gaussian mixture model to calculate probabilities from.

I have predefined means, covariances and weights and I simply want to calculate probabilities. However, sklearns Gaussian mixture function wants me to fit the data to samples.Which I don't need to do as I already know the parameters I want to fit.

```py
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

gmm = GaussianMixture(5, covariance_type = 'diag')
gmm.means_ = adj_means
gmm.covars_ = adj_variances
gmm.weights_ = weights

porto = [41.1579, -8.6291]

gmm.predict_proba(porto)
```

I would like for it to give me the probability of being to the bottom left of the central coordinates for porto. (I am fitting a gmm for final destination of taxi journeys and have the means, variances and weights from a mixed density network). However, I get the error.

"This GaussianMixture instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method."

but I don't want to fit to a sample I already have parameters.

Comment: Essentially I already have the pdf I want to fit and want to calculate specific probabilities.

Comment: I have the exact same question and don't understand how this is not yet implemented.

Comment: I am not sure if this will be helpful at all https://nbviewer.org/github/Jay-Haran/geogridmap/blob/master/README.ipynb. I essentially produced a large sample and then calculated cdfs etc from the sample. It's sort of a Bayesian approach I guess.

Comment: Here's the undelrying code https://github.com/jayharan/geogridmap/blob/master/geogridmap/code.py. I would ignore the bits about the mapping and just look at the functions like cdf.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to fit GMM into only your means. This way, GMM is fitted. Then set means, covariances and weights the way you want:

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(5, covariance_type = 'diag').fit(adj_means)
gmm.means_ = adj_means
gmm.covars_ = adj_variances
gmm.weights_ = weights

porto = [41.1579, -8.6291]

gmm.predict_proba(porto)
```

When you fit your GMM on `adj_means`, by default, the `gmm.means_` returns the `adj_means`. But it is necessary to set covariances and weights.